# When we forgive our offenders, does it mean we do not want God to punish them anymore?

Tags: love, forgiveness, hate

On of the biggest issues i have had with easily forgiving is because of some (ill advised?) thought that  doing so automatically exempts the person from punishment, i know its naive,  but when one is young, that would be the best one could do. But  i think that this may not be the case. I read in a christian leaders webpage (iv since lost the link to the page) that refusing to forgive because of some form of fear that the other party will sort of get away with it  'reveals a flawed eschatology' he argued since  even Christ when just about to be crucified asked Peter to put back his sword, since if  he saw fit,  Christ would have asked for angels. From this he argued that we do not necessarily have to think the  person will not be  punished to forgive, rather we are letting God  deal with punishing them. (Im talking about dealing with unforgiveness of major events, stuff that we may struggle with over long periods).

What does it mean (or involve) to forgive?

```
1. Let them of the hook so they do not get punished.
2. Let them off the hook so God is the one to punish them.
```

Comment: mike, I think it doesn't mean (1) nor (2), but, anyway, there is no real reason that make we think of such  complex an argument.

Comment: @ Mike Jesus said in Matthew 6:14 and 15 For if ye forgive men their trespasses, your heavenly Father will also forgive you: But if ye forgive not men their trespasses, neither will your Father forgive your trespasses. He also said in Luke 17:3  Take heed to yourselves: If thy brother trespass against thee, rebuke him; and if he repent, forgive him. So the real key is repentance, and if you repent but do not forgive anyone who has repented the wrong against you, do you have the right to expect God to forgive you?

Comment: but what happens to our expectation of justice? does forgiveness imply we let go of any desire for God to deal with them for their actions?

Comment: Welcome to the site. As you're a new visitor, I'd like to recommend the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help), [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: @ Mike Again should you expect God to be more generous to you than you are to others?

Comment: Remember there is a difference between punishment and discipline/consequences. We may not want someone to be punished while still wanting them to be disciplined.

Comment: "Forgiveness" is also used of (monetary) debts. When a debt is forgiven, you don't have to pay it back. This is what forgiveness means. If you forgive someone for wronging you, they no longer "owe you" for the wrong. This doesn't have to preclude some other form of punishment (from authority). It is a personal thing between the two of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that we forgive each other in order to more closely imitate Jesus. It doesn't have to do with *letting them off the hook*, nor do I believe it necessarily means we *expect God to judge them* later.

From Matthew 18:21-22,

> Then Peter came to Jesus and asked, "Lord, how many times shall I
>   forgive my brother or sister who sins against me? Up to seven times?"
>   Jesus answered, "I tell you, not seven times, but seventy-seven
>   times."

Here Jesus' response was meant to indicate that our forgiveness towards each other should be endless.

And I feel more directly from John 13:34-35,

> "A new command I give you: Love one another. As I have loved you, so
>   you must love one another. By this everyone will know that you are
>   my disciples, if you love one another."

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I don't think forgiveness means complete absolution from justice (just to clarify some definitions). I think it means absolution from any form of revenge, redemptive violence, punishment for its own sake, etc. We can forgive someone for a violent act, but if they are likely to continue their violence that doesn't mean allowing them to freely do so. We can forgive someone for a sin, but if they do not seek reconciliation nor repent, then (I think) justice can come in the form of protection and rehabilitation.

Protective and even rehabilitative measures may be *perceived* as punishment, but can be done out of love rather than hate (though this can be a *very* difficult distinction when emotional extremes are at play). Imprisonment, isolation, excommunication where there is no sign of repentance—sometimes it can be better to end relationships or leave communities where our own failings mean reconciliation is impossible, unwanted, or risks much more serious damage than going separate ways, for example.

In such cases, there may be forgiveness along-side what is *perceived* to be punishment. But I would argue that only if said 'punishment' is purely for protection and rehabilitation; not when the punishment is purely for its own sake.

I don't think we've truly forgiven someone if we're holding out for God (or society) to *punish* them. If we're holding onto the idea that they will be punished for their actions, that some justice remains to be served beyond protection and reconciliation/rehabilitation, then what have we really forgiven? It's probably better than nothing; a tool to alleviate *one's own* desire to carry out acts of revenge or punitive redemption, but if we still wish punishment and suffering on a person then we do not love them, we have not forgiven them.

---

I suspect some will take issue with my understanding, because of e.g. 'turning the other cheek', but my understanding of that concept is a *shaming of the oppressor* as a way of non-violent resistance, an alternate way of confronting the powerful, rather than completely passive, immediate and unquestioning forgiveness (which is not in itself resistive, does not challenge an unjust society, nor speak truth to power).

Comment: This is a brilliant explanation, its that part of differentiating between complete absolution and  absolution from punishment for its own sake. I never really got to understand that part. Got a link to some book that expounds on this difference in details?

Comment: I would recommend Engaging the Powers by Walter Wink. I don't think there's any single/best answer or explanation, but it provides one point of view which I've found interesting & helpful.